# Ruby: Find non-transparent PNG and convert into JPG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, png, transparency, alpha-transparency

What is the smartest way to find out if a PNG has transparency or not in Ruby? Is it OK if I just check if there's an alpha-channel? If yes: How do I check for an alpha-channel?

I'm writing a script that will convert all PNGs **without** transparency into smaller JPGs.

Thanks a lot for your help!

**UPDATE**: In the meantime I've written that script and you can find it at [Github](https://github.com/vazqujav/ImageSqueezer).

Comment: You do know that a JPEG ist not necessarily smaller than a PNG, don't you? This of course depends on JPEG compression, but the average quality/size ratio for PNGs is much better for web graphics, imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the alpha channel seems the most sensible thing to do. Is it safe to assume you are using [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/)? did you read the documentation?

```
>> require 'RMagick'
>> image = Magick::Image.read("a.png").first
>> image.alpha?
=> true
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#alpha_q

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the link! In my case, it seems that all PNGs do have an alpha-channel. Excuse my lame question, but is it possible to have a non-transparent PNG and still have an alpha-channel? That would mean that checking for an alpha-channel is not enough in my case.

Comment: you may link that special image in the question.

Comment: Check the link I posted to my script. Your suggestion doesn't work, because all PNGs do have an alpha channel. AFAIK: The value of the alpha channel sets the transparency, not its existence.